# What to upgrade, RAM over capacity

Tags: linux, vps, dedicated-server

I'm currently running a series of sites on a single VPS. My RAM usage has been continually going over capacity and, even after upgrading, I seem to be using all of my allotted RAM and burstable RAM...

It seems like I should just get a dedicated server instead of upgrading my VPS again, given the kind of traffic I've been getting. But, I've never had a dedicated server before, but what should I be looking for here? It doesn't seem like dedicated servers have much larger RAM allocation than my VPS. Why would I pay a higher price for one?

Thanks, I'm relatively new to being a sysadmin, sorry if this is an obvious answer.

EDIT: Sorry for the lack of details. I currently am running on a linux VPS with 1GB RAM / 2GB burstable. Since my sites are growing, I'm just looking to scale them up in the most efficient way possible. Is an upgraded VPS the way to go or a dedicated server? Thanks.

Comment: Eat http://www.linuxatemyram.com

Comment: Is this causing performance issues and that's why you want to upgrade? Also, you are giving no information about your site, what you are trying to accomplish, or anything. A little more detail would be helpful. Linux will use whatever ram you give it naturally. So you need to ask yourself am I having performance issues.

Comment: You also do not say how much ram. I have 48gb virtual servers.

Comment: Sorry, updated description

Answer (score 0):

First off is this a Windows server or Linux?    Under Linux you server will use all available ram.  You need to look at how much you have in buffers and cached.  If your buffers and cache are really low then you would need to look at more ram.  As for the dedicated servers all that means is that the cpu, memory, disk is all for you where as on a vps you have to share the load with others.

Answer (score 0):

IF you only host some sites on your vps and you think this is a reason you need more RAM and if its true that you use Apache as your web server, i s uggest using a async, non blocking web server like NGINX instead of apache. the Apache memory footprint is high and switching web server has highly impact on your performance without the need to